# display images path that not loaded in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to display(or alert) the images loaded or not loaded using .load() & .error() functions in jquery.
Currently it only displays the last image name.
I need all image names that not loaded.

Is there have any possible way to do this in javascript?

Code that I am using is..

```
$('<img />').load(function(){
                                    alert(item_source);
}).attr('src',item_source,'title',title);
```

The full code with loop is..

```
for(var i = 0; i < items_count; ++i){
        var item_source = data1[i];
        var cnt         = 0;
        var img=new Image();
        var title=$('span')[index].innerHTML;
        $('<img />').load(function(){
            var $image = $(this);

            ++cnt;
            resizeCenterImage($image);
            $ps_container.append($image);

            var r       = Math.floor(Math.random()*41)-20;
            if(cnt < items_count){
                $image.css({
                    '-moz-transform'    :'rotate('+r+'deg)',
                    '-webkit-transform' :'rotate('+r+'deg)',
                    'transform'         :'rotate('+r+'deg)'
                });
            }
            if(cnt == items_count){
                $loading.remove();
                $ps_container.show();
                $ps_close.show();
                $ps_play.show();
                $ps_overlay.show();
            }

        }).attr('src',item_source,'title',title);

    }
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_complete

Comment: that's not how you set multiple attributes, you need to pass an object to [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes) also can you explain the behavior you're experiencing, are you getting multiple alerts with the same value or only one alert? can you share the context of this code, is it inside a loop?

Comment: It should alert the image names that loaded. Currently alerts only last image name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that by the time the load function runs, the variable you want to alert has already been modified and now holds the last value set. Use `this.src` instead to grab the source of the current image:

```
$('<img />').load(function(){
    alert(this.src);
}).attr({src:item_source,title:title});
```

Also if you want to set multiple attributes you need to pass an object to [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes)